# Kotlin - Cant init a companion object value

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to deliver the itemListener to my viewHolder in order to capture the element that I click, I have done this

```
class MyAdapter(itemListener:RecyclerViewClickListener){

 companion object{
        var itemListener: RecyclerViewClickListener? = null
    }

    init {
        this.equipmentSearchList = equipmentList
        this.itemListener = itemListener
    }
}
```

But I cant do `this.itemListener = itemListener`

How to solve it ?

Comment: The object you're being passed in is named `listener`, not `itemListener`.

Comment: don't use >> 'this'

Comment: If I dont use this, it says val cannot be reasigned, but I dont have any itemListener of type val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare like this & change name of input variable from main constructor

```
class MyAdapter(itemListenerMAIN:RecyclerViewClickListener){

 companion object{
        var itemListener: RecyclerViewClickListener? = null
    }

    init {
      //don't use >> this. 
        itemListener = itemListenerMAIN
    }
}
```